# ObjectBox's Box Object

Tags: android, objectbox

So I decide to try out ObjectBox today :), but In the ObjectBox docs I saw this:

**To see how new notes are added to the database, take a look at the NoteActivity class. First of all we have to prepare a Box object for our Note class, which we do in onCreate():**

```
notesBox = ((App) getApplication()).getBoxStore().boxFor(Note.class);
```

*I  then did this:*

```
BoxStore boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(MainActivity.this).build();
    Box notesBox = ((App) getApplication()).getBoxStore().boxFor(store.class);
```

The thing is that the portion of the code that says '(App)', the symbol 'App' cannot be resolved, I thought it like meant context, but it didn't still solve it even when I put 'this'. So what actually is the issue :/, am I doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: I guess that App is a class which extends the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class

Comment: Yeahhh, that could be it..

Comment: Yeah, thanks that was it, it's better understood when the full source code is seen on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this question. We just updated http://objectbox.io/documentation/how-to-get-started/ and added a note:

> In the demo project, "App" is the name of the class extending
>   android.app.Application – a good place to store BoxStore.